# pipelinedb consuming kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, pipelinedb

When I create a stream in the pipeline and it starts consuming of a topic, it does not appear in the active consmidores of my topic, what do I do so that it appears there?

[No consumer appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1j5.jpg)

How I created the stream

```
CREATE STREAM pipeline_kafka.summary_device_stream(pack json);
SELECT pipeline_kafka.consume_begin('topicSummaryDevice', 'pipeline_kafka.summary_device_stream', format := 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where that value is getting pulled from in your attached screenshot, but I'm guessing it only applies to consumers that are storing offsets in Kafka.

You can store offsets in Kafka with `pipeline_kafka` by passing a `group_id` parameter to the consumer command, like so:

```
SELECT pipeline_kafka.consume_begin('topicSummaryDevice',
   'pipeline_kafka.summary_device_stream',
    group_id := 'consumer_group_id',
    format := 'json');
```

Comment: grave error :( 

**SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function pipeline_kafka.consume_begin(unknown, unknown, group_id => unknown, format => unknown) does not exist
  Dica: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Posição: 8
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function pipeline_kafka.consume_begin(unknown, unknown, group_id => unknown, format => unknown) does not exist
  Dica: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Posição: 8**

Comment: What is the exact command you entered that caused that error?

Comment: this command ...

`SELECT pipeline_kafka.consume_begin('topicNotificationProcess', 'pipeline_kafka.sensor_event_process_stream',   format := 'json', group_id:= 'groupEventProcess'; batchsize := 4330, parallelism := 5, start_offset := -1);`

Comment: That command has a `;` after the `group_id` argument instead of a `,` which actually isn't even valid syntax. Other than that, you should verify that the `pipeline_kafka` extension is installed by checking the output of `\dx`.

Comment: I put it wrong here but I used the "," after group_id....

The extension is installed, the consumer works, it just does not appear in a group in the kafka.